# Python Pandas: Label data with condition on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as below:

```
 ID   Label
 1      1
 2     NaN
 3      3
 4     NaN
 5      1
 6     NaN
 7     NaN
 8      3
```

What I want to do is at the label column if the row is between label 1 and 3, I want to label it as 2. 
Example output:

```
 ID   Label
 1      1
 2      2
 3      3
 4     NaN
 5      1
 6      2
 7      2 
 8      3
```

What is the best way to do this. Thank you=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we make three masks (read: we mark rows with `True` and `False`)

1. All the rows which are `NaN` with [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)
2. Rows which are `1` after we use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) (forwardfill).
3. Rows which are `3` after we use [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) to catch edgecase (see comment @busybear)

Then we conditionally fill in the value `2` if **all 3** conditions are `True` with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = df['Label'].isna()
m2 = df['Label'].ffill().eq(1)
m3 = df['Label'].bfill().eq(3)

df['Label'] = np.where(m1 & m2 & m3, 2, df['Label'])
```

---

```
   ID  Label
0   1    1.0
1   2    2.0
2   3    3.0
3   4    NaN
4   5    1.0
5   6    2.0
6   7    2.0
7   8    3.0
```

Comment: I would add one more condition for backfilling equal to 3. If there is something like `[1, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, 3]`, it won't set first chunk to 2.

Comment: Yes it will still do the forwardfill. The `.eq` is _after_ the forwardfill to mark the rows which were `NaN`. Just test for yourself: `pd.Series([1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 3]).ffill()`

Comment: I was assuming the OP didn't want the first chunk in my example to be changed. Adding the backfill would result in `[1, nan, nan, 1, 2, 2, 3]` instead. Up to OP I guess!

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
s=(df.Label.ffill()+df.Label.bfill())
s2=(df.Label.ffill().astype(str)+df.Label.bfill().astype(str))
df.loc[df.Label.isnull()&s2.eq('1.03.0'),'Label']=s/2
df
Out[528]: 
   ID  Label
0   1    1.0
1   2    2.0
2   3    3.0
3   4    NaN
4   5    1.0
5   6    2.0
6   7    2.0
7   8    3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think subtracting `bfill` from `ffill` will give rows where value is `NaN` and monotonic-increase from 1 to 3 which have value -2:

```
df.Label.ffill().sub(df.Label.bfill())

Out[692]:
0    0.0
1   -2.0
2    0.0
3    2.0
4    0.0
5   -2.0
6   -2.0
7   -2.0
8    0.0
Name: Label, dtype: float64
```

So, doing `eq(-2)` on it to create mask and assign `2` to `loc`

```
m = df.Label.ffill().sub(df.Label.bfill()).eq(-2)
df.loc[m, 'Label'] = 2


Out[712]:
   ID  Label
0   1    1.0
1   2    2.0
2   3    3.0
3   4    NaN
4   5    1.0
5   6    2.0
6   7    2.0
7   8    2.0
8   9    3.0
```

---

**Note**: I added one more row to your sample to test cases of 3 consecutive `NaN`s